# Eureka timeout exception

Tags: microservices, netflix-eureka

I am new to micro-services and I am getting below exception. I am getting this only some times and I am not able to proceed.

> eureka_1            | 2019-02-25 15:08:22.666 ERROR 1 ---
>   [target_eureka-7] c.n.e.cluster.ReplicationTaskProcessor   : It seems
>   to be a socket read timeout exception, it will retry later. if it
>   continues to happen and some eureka node occupied all the cpu time,
>   you  should set property 'eureka.server.peer-node-read-timeout-ms' to
>   a bigger value

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you set `eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone` ?

Answer (score 2):

I got this error while trying to run my microservices in a virtual machine. When I raised VM memory from 2.5 to 10 GB it disappeared.

By default in Docker for Windows specified only 2Gb. So try to rise memory volume.